# regex for character code 0 in java

Tags: java, regex

How does one write a regular expression in java that will match all strings without the character code zero?

I've tried:

```
Pattern.compile ("[^\0]");
```

and

```
Pattern.compile ("[^\u0000]");
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are obviously missing a + after the character class.

Comment: Any reason you want to use a regular expression here instead of `if (!text.contains("\0"))`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your first regex is almost right, but it only matches a single character that is not `\0`. Try changing it to:

```
Pattern.compile ("[^\0]+");
```

This should match one-or-more (`+`) characters that are not `\0`.